# AlertView's Height Expand Automatically on iPhone 4

Tags: objective-c, iphone-4

Currently,I am developing one app in which i set simple alert on one button click.
All operation performed very well on all device but when i run my app on iPhone 4 alert's height automatically increase and my subview's which add in alert its layout is not looking good.
What is issue is generating i cant find out please suggest me some solution.

Comment: What AlertView? What's your current code?

Comment: Are you using  a custom view as Alert View ? because technically you cant increase alertview frame.

Comment: a=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Choose Photos" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
 a.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0,a.bounds.size.width + 100,300 +216 +20);
 [a show];

Comment: Add your code to your question (with format). Why do you change the bounds of the `UIAlertView`?

Comment: because i add two button as a subview in alert, so i set bound but it only works 4s 5 5s and 6 or ipad. some times it exapnd when i use picker view but some time it not expand why it happens?

Comment: That's weird, because you can't add subview anymore to UIAlertView, or at least, this won't be accepted by Apple.

Comment: ok but i add button in custom UIView before this, but view display center in portrait, When i rotate device in landscape view not set in center.  so how i set my data like alert. i used many controls but not work properly.